# Relying on the (copy) attribute to copy NSMutableDictionary causes crash

Tags: objective-c

The following program relies on the copy
attribute to copy a NSMutableDictionary.
The copy is apparently ok, but, if I try
to add a new element to the copy, the program crashes.
Is it some kind of bug?
PS. If it matters it's NON ARC

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Dog: NSObject
@property (copy) NSMutableDictionary *dict;
@end

@implementation Dog
@synthesize dict;

- (id) init
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
    dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) print {
    for (id key in dict) {
    printf("%s --> %s\n", [key UTF8String], [dict[key] UTF8String] );
    }
}

@end

//------------------------------------------------------

int main() {
    Dog *dog1 = [[Dog alloc] init];
    Dog *dog2 = [[Dog alloc] init];

    dog1.dict[@"color"] = @"black";
    dog2.dict = dog1.dict;
    [dog2 print];
    // the print shows that dog2.dict is indeed a copy of dog1.dict
    // lldb shows that it is a shallow copy, which I guess is ok
    // since values are immutable.
    // ... so far so good.
    dog1.dict[@"tail"] = @"long";   // This goes smoothly
    // 
    // But...
    dog2.dict[@"tail"] = @"long";
    // here program crashes with the following message
    //
    // -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100108ee0
    //*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x100108ee0'
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT:
If I replace the line

```
dog2.dict = dog1.dict;
```

with

```
[dog2.dict addEntriesFromDictionary: dog1.dict];
```

then it works. There is no crash.
So, OK, this is the correct way of doing it.
But my point is: don't I deserve at least a warning
from the compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've broken some rules here, which is why it's going badly for you. As a rule, you should not return or accept `NSMutableDictionary` as a property. There are exceptions (and you have to code around that), but generally you should not. To code this correctly, you need to separate your interface from your implementation.

The correct interface is:

```
@interface Dog: NSObject
@property (copy) NSDictionary *dict;
@end
```

This object promises to accept and return NSDictionary, and it promises that the accepted and returned NSDictionaries will be independent copies, so the caller doesn't need to worry about mutability issues. We then need to implement those promises:

```
@implementation Dog {
    NSMutableDictionary *mutableDict;
}

- (id) init
{
    if ( (self = [super init]) ) {
        mutableDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) print {
    for (id key in mutableDict) {
        printf("%s --> %s\n", [key UTF8String], [mutableDict[key] UTF8String] );
    }
}

- (NSDictionary *)dict {
    return [mutableDict copy]; // Add an -autorelease if this is MRC
}

- (void)setDict: (NSDictionary *)newValue {
    // I'm going to pretend this is ARC; for MRC, code this in your style.
    mutableDict = [newValue mutableCopy];
}

@end
```

On the other hand, if you really do want to share state with an NSMutableDictionary, you should not copy it, you should retain it to make clear the semantics.

```
@interface Dog: NSObject
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary *dict;
@end
```

And this makes it (hopefully) clear to the caller that this is shared state and should be treated as such, and the caller should make copies if they so desire. But you generally should avoid this. And if you do go this way, I would call the property `mutableDict` or something like that to make it clear that this is unusual. For an example, see `-[NSAttributedString mutableString]`.

There's not really a "mutable, but independent copy" semantic in ObjC property annotations, and I wouldn't create one unless you have a very strong need (generally performance related). I would generally just return an immutable copy and let the caller make their own mutable copy.

One more side note: Sometimes Cocoa implements "returns an immutable copy" as "just return the mutable one, cast to an immutable type." This improves performance by avoiding the copy, at the cost of sometimes the data changing behind your back. As an example, look at the docs for `-[NSView subviews]`. In my opinion you should avoid this pattern unless it is critical for performance (and even then, I'd make a special method like `-subviewsBackingStore` or something silly like that to make it clear "this is weird."

Answer (score 2):

`copy` attribute creates an NSDictionary instance, not `NSMutableDictionary`, that's why it's crashing.
First, change the property to `retain` from `copy`:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* duct;
```

Then you can do the following:

```
Dog *dog2 = [[Dog alloc] init];
dog2.dict = [dog1.dict mutableCopy];
```

Comment: I replaced the line
`dog2.dict = dog1.dict;`
with
`dog2.dict = [dog1.dict mutableCopy];`
It keeps crashing with the same message.

Comment: Besides, If I add a key to a NSDictionary, the compiler produces an error.

Comment: sorry, missed something: you need to change the `dict` property from `(copy)` to `(retain)`:
`@property (retain) NSMutableDictionary* dict;`

Comment: But I want an independent copy. With the retain, dog1.dict and dog2.dict would be two pointers to the _same_ dictionary. I found the correct way (see the EDIT to the post), but I think I should get some kind of warning...

Comment: There is no mutableCopy property annotation, unfortunately.   So if you want that behavior, you need to implement it yourself in the setter.  copy semantics will call the -copy method, which will turn any NSMutableDictionary (or NSMutableArray, etc.) into its immutable counterpart, which you can no longer modify.  In general, mutable collections are best not made public properties (or made read-only if they are, so nobody outside can call the setter), and have strong/retain semantics.

Comment: Ok, I understand but (sorry if I insist): the language offers me a seducingly simple sintax `dict2 = dict1` where dict2 is _mutable_ with the _copy_ attribute. Shouldn't the compiler realize that something is likely to go wrong and say "Hey bro, you probably don't want to do that", like it does in many much more harmless situations?